# micro uniquestamp, what is this?

Tags: php, api, curl, nonce

Im developing a little software based on API requests with php cURL.

I encountered a problem with private requests of API. One of the parameters of the request is "nonce" (unix timestamp), but the response is "invalid nonce".

Contacting the assistance, they answer me that:

> "*Invalid Nonce is sent when nonce you sent is smaller or equal to the nonce that was previously sent.*"

And,

"*if you make 2 requests at same second you need to increase nonce for 2nd request (you can use micro uniquestamp so that in one second you can create 1000000 unique nonces in 1 second).*"

**My question is**: What function can I use to solve this problem!? I tried microtime() function, but I get the same error.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

My code:

```
$unix_time = time();
$microtime = number_format(microtime(true), 5, '', '')
$message = $unix_time.$customer_id.$API_KEY; //nonce + customer id + api key
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $API_SECRET);

$ticker_url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btceur";
$balance_url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/btceur/";

$param_array = array(
    "key" => $API_KEY,
    "signature" => strtoupper($signature),
    "nonce" => $microtime  
);

switch($_POST['action']){
    case 'ticker_btceur':
        ticker_btceur($param_array, $ticker_url);
        break;
    case 'balance_btceur':
        balance_btceur($param_array, $balance_url);
        break;
}

function ticker_btceur($da, $b_url){ // cURL GET 

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $b_url."?key=".$da['key']."&signature=".$da['signature']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/cacert.pem");

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
        echo "Errore: ". curl_error($ch)." - Codice errore: ".curl_errno($ch);
    }
    else{
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

 function balance_btceur($pa, $b_url){ // cURL POST 

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $b_url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($pa));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($pa));

 if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
    echo "Errore: ". curl_error($ch)." - Codice errore: ".curl_errno($ch);
 }
 else{
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     echo $result;
 }
 curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: perhaps PHP's microtime format `sec msec` is not recognized by this API, check here https://www.php.net/microtime

Comment: @PeterM In fact, I get the same error. But I don't know how to solve the problem. Should I still ask for assistance?

Comment: `$message = $unix_time.$customer_id.$API_KEY;` should be `$message = $microtime.$customer_id.$API_KEY;` as `$microtime` is the nonce your sending up and using in the message. Remove `$unix_time = time();` its confusing you.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks but it is the same thing

Comment: @ClaudioFiamingo Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @user2203703 no.. they answered me: "Kindly note that the last "invalid nonce" we received was because nonce was same as a previous nonce: Key (Key), Signature (Signature), Permission (balance), IP address (ip_address), Nonce (*1555243382886328*), Stored nonce (*1555243382886328*)"

Comment: @user2203703 i don't know how to solve :(

Comment: @user2203703 ok... thank you very much

Comment: @user2203703 This page has been removed.... can you rewrite the email address pls?!

Answer (score 0):

`microtime()` is current Unix timestamp with microseconds and it's different than normal microseconds time (1 sceond = 1000000 microseconds), so they are not the samething.

If the service provider is asking you to send the time in Unix timestamp with microseconds then you have to use:

```
$time = microtime(true);
```

Also you can make it random by using `rand()` to be like that:

```
// Increase the time in random value between 10 and 100 in microtime
$time = microtime(true) + rand(10, 100);
```

If they asking you to do it in microseconds time then use `rand()` like that:

```
$time = rand(1000,10000000);
```

Comment: They asking me for "unix timestamp". I tried: time(), microtime(true) and rand(1000,10000000) but the error is the same.

Comment: time() just working with public functions... I don't understand what they mean with "micro uniquestamp"

Comment: for the second request try to use : `microtime(true) + rand(10, 100)`

Comment: You have to ask them to explain more and give you some examples.

Comment: @user2203703 `rand` won't work right? Since he has to maintain incremental values.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai right... i think the problem maybe is that with rand and microtime(true) the value is a float (1555147863.1191)... maybe it should be an integer? Without decimal digits?

Comment: @ClaudioFiamingo Yes, you should check the spec of the API or do an OPTIONS call on it to get the details (if they support this). Dropping the decimal might work.

Comment: @ClaudioFiamingo Use `number_format(microtime(true), 5, '', '')`, increase the value `5` as per your concurrent usage requirement.

Comment: @ClaudioFiamingo your code not going to work as you expect, i just read the guideline, some miss in your code, i don't believe that you will get the help that you are looking here, you need to hire a freelancer.

Comment: @ClaudioFiamingo contact their developers, they may able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that API requires microseconds, here is function to get microseconds:

```php
function microseconds()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return $sec . ($usec * 1000000);
}


echo microseconds();
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

my best guess is that they mean:

```
$stamp=(string)(int)(microtime(true)*1000000);
```

this stamp will change 1 million times per second, depending on when you generate it, it looks something like

```
string(16) "1555177383042022"
```

.. just note that this code won't work properly on a 32bit system, if your code needs 32bit php compatibility then do this instead:

```
$stamp2=bcmul(number_format(microtime(true),18,".",""),"1000000",0);
```